# What constitutes high cardinality for a feature in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-encoding

I have found various articles discussing methods of dealing with high-cardinality features, some applicable to both nominal and ordinal data (One Hot Encoding, for example) and others specific to one type of data.

But I have yet to find a mathematical way to prove a feature is indeed high cardinality... how can I determine that?

My thesis advisor suggests that I just go ahead and try various machine learning frameworks and see if I get an acceptable accuracy... though I'm not convinced that getting low accuracy will necessarily imply that one of my features has too high a cardinality.

For what it's worth, there are 50 potential values. How can I determine a good goal for reducing the number of features?